# How to set and get a vector in local storage?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What would be the idiomatic Clojure way to do this. In js we can use json to stringify the array and then save this in local storage, but I am not sure what would the ideal solution be in clojure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean browser local storage.

You could just (de)serialize your Clojure value as an EDN string.

Comment: Yes browser local storage, I solved this problem by `str( vector)` and `cljs.reader/read-string ...`

Comment: You probably just want to use `clojure.edn/read-string` though

Comment: You'll want to use `pr-str` to serialize stuff, `str` works fine for vectors but `pr-str` is the way to go. `clojure.edn` is just an alias for `cljs.reader` in CLJS so they are effectively the same. An alternative to those is using `transit-cljs`.

Comment: Seems so , at that time I saw `cljs.reader` on re-frame tutorial so used it. Thank you.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/daveliepmann/cf923140702c8b1de301

Answer (score 1):

Please see `spit` and `slurp` from the [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).  It can be found through this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).